# Magento custom module not using the correct include path

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom Magento payment module. I have created the file:
/var/www/app/etc/modules/CustomerParadigm_NoPay.xml
which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <CustomerParadigm_NoPay>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CustomerParadigm_NoPay>
    </modules>
</config>
```

For what everreason Magento is throwing this error:

> Warning:
>   include(Mage/Model/Nopay.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or
>   directory  in
>   /var/www/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on
>   line 93

which is obviously not the right path, since I told Magento to look in the local folder. If anyone has any suggestions let me know.

I have also added this to my .htaccess file

```
php_value include_path ".:/var/www/app/code/local"
```

Comment: Your include path is fine, it's your module's config.xml that's the problem (not CustomerParadigm_NoPay.xml, but instead etc/config.xml). Post the contents of that here and someone will be able to tell you why Magento's trying to instantiate the wrong class (resulting in the deceptive error message you're seeing)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "_" in this config, because Magento will try to break "CustomerParadigm_NoPay" as directory `CustomerParadigm` and `NoPay` as class in this directory.

Comment: I don't think it matters in the context of the `<modules>` node. The name given isn't used as a model class, that can only happen in a `Mage::getModel()` call somewhere else. Besides, lots of other modules use an underscore without a problem.

Comment: I admit that the "_" may not be a problem.
@benk, it would be nice to see your config.xml and place where You call the model.